# Can I safely use my English Xbox 360 in Slovakia?

Tags: xbox-360

just a quick question for anybody with the knowledge. I've brought my Xbox 360 from England with me to Slovakia. Can I use it here or will it blow up if plug it in?

Answer (score 1):

The Voltage in the area is Fine for the version Xbox you have.
Both are 230 volts, just verify it on the back of the power pack.
This is an UK console not a USA, correct?

If it all matches, getting an adapter will work.

Comment: I think he should also take a look at frequency expressed in Hz

Comment: If you want to be safe, the way to go is to buy a replacement power supply for your Xbox in your destination country (assuming you're going to be staying long enough to make the expense worth it) -- but if you can verify that the voltage (e.g. 230V) and frequency (e.g. 50Hz) are the same, you can just buy a replacement cord much cheaper, without having to fuss with adapters that may be flimsy and unreliable (which could be fatal to your Xbox if it's bad enough)

Comment: That said, I just looked online and both UK & Slovakia are 230V/50Hz, so a replacement cord would indeed be your best bet, and should cost less than €20, probably under €10 if you look online.

Answer (score -1):

**No you cannot**. The outlet's they use in Slovakia are far different than the ones used in England, for this you need a travel adapter.

Here is an example of the power outlet type used in Slovakia

[image]

which is far different than the outlets we use in England. A travel adapter will be useful because you can plug in your English adapter on one end, and it will have the other side attached to (usually multiple) different outlet types depending on the country.

Comment: "my xbox 360 from England" and you give an answer talking about American consoles?

Comment: @Powerlord the answer is basically the same, but my bad. I didn't see that.

Comment: Also, you did not address whether there are other issues in consideration like region zoning or restrictions. You did not mention if voltage will be an issue: i.e. if you use an adapter you still use the same voltage and current, there is no conversion in standard travel adapter. Will the console be fried ?

Comment: @BlueTrin, question states "Can I use it here or will it blow up if plug it in?" and also this is a year old question, although it might be better if someone gave a better answer, it is best to not touch it.